# Can't get the Authorization code from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Signin in my android app. 
I followed the google guidelines to the point 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth

I want to get authorization code from google and then send it back to my server so that server can process the code and send that to google to get access token.

```
public static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog loginDialog;

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    /* RequestCode for resolutions to get GET_ACCOUNTS permission on M */
    private static final int RC_PERM_GET_ACCOUNTS = 2;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;

    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .build();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the device, that the selected
        // account has granted any requested permissions to our app and that we were able to
        // establish a service connection to Google Play services.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + bundle);
        mShouldResolve = false;

        new GetIdTokenTask().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            onSignInClicked();
        }
    }

    private void onSignInClicked() {
        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
        mShouldResolve = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }

            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    private class GetIdTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            String code = "";
            String sc = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

            String SERVER_CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYY.apps.googleusercontent.com";

            String scope = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:" + sc;
            try {
                code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scope);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
                return null;
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
                return null;
            }
            return code;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ID token: " + result);
            if (result != null) {
                // Successfully retrieved ID Token
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://example.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback");

                try {
                    List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idToken", result));
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    final String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Signed in as: " + responseBody);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending ID token to backend.", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending ID token to backend.", e);
                }
            } else {
                // There was some error getting the ID Token
                // ...
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.dialog_error_login_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

When I try to get the code from

```
code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
```

where my scope is

```
String scope = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:" + sc;
```

where sc = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

and CLIENT_ID is the web server client id which I have generated in the developers console.

I am getting

```
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at com.example.login.LoginActivity$GetIdTokenTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:202)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at com.example.login.LoginActivity$GetIdTokenTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:179)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-19 06:54:39.535 26012-26510/com.example.login E/LoginActivity:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't know why am I getting this error. I tried changing the Scope but as I use CLIENT_ID it gives me this error.

If I use Scope as below:

```
String scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
```

It gives me permission error:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Please any help is much appreciated. Been stuck for almost 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

In your onConnectionFailed, you must add the following:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CONSENT = 2;
         @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
                    // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
                    // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

                    if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
         if(!connectionResult.hasResolution()){
                        if (mGoogleApiClient.isUserResolvableError(connectionResult.getErrorCode())){
                              Dialog dialog = mGoogleApiClient.getErrorDialog(activityContext, connectionResult.getErrorCode(), REQUEST_CONSENT);
                             dialog.show();               
                             return;
                        }

                    }
                        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                            try {
                                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                                mIsResolving = true;
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                                mIsResolving = false;
                                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

A dialog consent will be shown to user which upon accepting should solve UserRecoverableException.